# FireDAC: Shared Lock on Table during SELECT-Statement without FetchAll

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firedac

I am using Delphi XE 7 with FireDAC to connect to MS SQL Server. I use the options `lockmode pessimistic` with `locktpoint immediate` for the Connection to force that a record only can be edited by one person at the same time. Furthermore I only fetch 50 records for SELECT-Querys.

Now I have got the problem that a Query whith more than 50 records generates a Shared Lock (S) on the Table of the SELECT-Statement and so no one can edit a record of this Table anymore. To edit a record is not able until all the data from the Query is fetched. As we use it to display the Data in a Grid this depends on Users interactivity and that´s the Problem.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this Problem without doing a "FetchAll" for the SELECT-Statement?

regards
Maggi

Comment: I know nothing about Delphi and FireDAC, but [SQL Server has a `ROWLOCK` hint you can use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187373.aspx) to prevent lots of rowlocks escalating into a full-on table lock. Might be worth a try...

Comment: As you're discovering, you are making life difficult for yourself by trying to lock rows on the server, because this gets in the way of users trying to concurrently access the data.  It's less problematic to use client-side optimistic locking.  If you're worried about another user having changed the same row, you can check for that by re-reading the row before trying to update it.  Or, if only your app will be accessing the data, mark the row as "in user by user X" when they start editing - though obviously users will "go away" from time to time.

Comment: Do you really have a high probability of users modifying the same record? See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598(v=sql.110).aspx for a deep explanation on how locking works in SQL Server (especially escalation), and what options you have. READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT could help you, but you have to know how it impacts your application.